# Understanding subdomain url mod-rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need to understand url mod-rewrite but couldn't get the basic at all.

I want to change **www.domain.com/folder/page.php?id=1** to **1.domain.com**

1. I created a wildcard subdomain **(*.domain.com)** and the problem is, where should I point the subdomain to? is it **public_html/** or **public_html/folder/** ?
2. Which htaccess file should I modify? is it in **public_html/** or **public_html/folder/** ?
3. What's the link to the page.php? is it **a href="1.domain.com"** or **a href="www.domain.com/folder/page.php?id=1"**

Thank you very much :D really appreciate your help :D

EDIT :

.htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ /file.php?item=%2 [QSA,nc]
```

I typed 1.domain.com but it's showing no server found.

Comment: Been trying for hours but couldn't get it. can somebody help please?

Comment: Do you want to do a redirect or rewrite? from or to 1.domain.com?

Comment: The real url is page.php?id=1. But I want the url to appear like this, 1.domain.com. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That strongly depends on your setup. Point it to the same directory where you'll put the .htaccess in. Most of the time a subdomain points to an extra directory i.e. public_html/1/ where you can put the .htaccess in and separate it's logic from the rest of your website.
2. That one where the subdomain points to, see answer 1. :)
3. The link will be a href="1.domain.com"

Comment: Thank you very much :D will try it now :D. What if there are other subdomains?

Comment: Its not working. I put the .htaccess file in the "/1" directory. Then, I pointed the "*.domain.com" to "/1" directory. This is my .htaccess code :

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /file.php?item=%2 [QSA,nc]

Thanky ou very much :D. really appreciate your help :D

Comment: please post your htaccess code in the question, it's really hard to read it in the comments and describe what's actually happening now

Comment: Okay :D. Posted in question :D

Comment: Did you configure your DNS when "no server found" is shown? is the name resolving to the correct IP? Do you have an entry in your access.log for the request?

Comment: Thanky ou very much :D. *.domain.com in A with correct shared hosting ip. Sorry but I never heard of that access.log request? Is it in the access-log folder? It's empty.

Comment: The location depends on your configuration. But access-log folder pretty sound like the correct folder. Currently it seems for me as your hosting is not configured correctly, so the request never reaches your specidifed folder.

Comment: What happens if you just copy an index.html file in the /1/ subfolder and remove the .htaccess. Is it displayed?

Comment: Still doesnt work. Just server not found. My actual url is www.domain.com/index.php?dm=8. There are other subdomain I created that works perfectly. But wildcard subdomain is not working at all.

Comment: So it's really in your server config and not related to your .htaccess. Call your hoster, there's something messed up.

Comment: It's already working !. Maybe it's takes time for the dns to be prepared. But Why I cant access it without entering www. ?